# Unable to upgrade 11.04 to 11.10

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed in my laptop and tried to upgrade it by opening the update manager and  and making the necessary settings in **settings - updates - release upgrade - normal releases** and then hitting the **check** button. But nothing appeared indicating later version is available to be upgraded. When I run the following

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

below is the result that appeared.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Also I am unable to watch YouTube videos in the Firefox 15.0 in my Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

Comment: @Mitch:Even this too I did before my post on this forum, for which the following was the beginning, middle and ending portion of the output.

`Get:1 ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in natty InRelease Ign ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in natty InRelease Get:2 ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in natty-updates InRelease` ...

`Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease`

and
`W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/CODENAME/Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Do as Mitch Said:

then type this command in the Terminal:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I did the one you suggested for which the following is the result `Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found` Appreciate further help

Comment: ok try this one: do-release-upgrade -d

Comment: :Tried `do-release-upgrade-d` for which also the same `Checking for a new ubuntu release No new release found` was appeared. :(

Comment: Appreciate further help

Comment: This won't likely be sufficient to solve the current problem, but please note that, to succeed, `do-release-upgrade` must be run as root (so run `sudo do-release-upgrade` instead).

Comment: @kasi Heck the above comment :)